# Custom Resource Backed Lambda "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a custom resource backed lambda caused the cloudformation "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS" forever and can not delete

```
import pymysql
import os
import json
import boto3
from botocore.vendored import requests


def handler(event, context):
    try:
        if event['RequestType'] == 'Create' or event['RequestType'] == 'Update':
            print("Create or Update")
            # some database operation
            respond_cloudformation(event, "SUCCESS")
        else:
            respond_cloudformation(event, "SUCCESS")
            return
    except:
        respond_cloudformation(event, "SUCCESS")

def respond_cloudformation(event, status, data=None):
    responseBody = {
        'Status': status,
        'Reason': 'See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream',
        'PhysicalResourceId': 'Custom Lambda Function',
        'StackId': event['StackId'],
        'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
        'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId'],
        'Data': data
    }

    print('Response = ' + json.dumps(responseBody))
    requests.put(event['ResponseURL'], data=json.dumps(responseBody))
```

Comment: Check your cloudformation code. It is probably not the python code causing the problem. It is something in your cloudformation template.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Firstly, it is NOT forever. The stack creation/update will eventually time out. To speed things up you can contact aws support so they could manually terminate the stack. But for custom resources i think the timeout happends after 1 hour.

Secondly, check your AWS CloudWatch logs. The running lambda produces all logs there. You will definitelly see some kind of crash there.

Thirdly, I am almost guaranteed your lambda crashes because it does not have a pymysql module installed. Create a lambda deployment package if you want to operate with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a custom resource in CloudFormation and you fail to catch errors properly, the CloudFormation resource will remain in a 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS' state for the defined timeout time (by default: 1 hour), given that the Lambda invocation failed 3 times.

You can either be very quick after deploying and "fix" the Lambda on the spot so that when CloudFormation invokes the Lambda it will not return an error, OR if you're too late (after 3 tries): Fix the Lambda function and cancel the stack update. Rolling back also invokes the Lambda. If the Lambda is broken, then this will also take the defined timeout time.

If you've missed all windows of opportunity, the rollback will fail. You will have to continue rolling back preserving the failed resource.

Protip: define sane CFN timeouts ;-)